# How/where does a GoPro camera store HiLight tags?

Tags: video, video-editing, highlighting, gopro

### My Question in a Nutshell

How/where does a GoPro camera store [HiLight tags](http://gopro.com/support/articles/what-is-hilight-tagging-and-how-does-it-work)?

### Where I have Looked for the HiLight Tags

I have already tried to find the created tags in the following locations – to no avail:

- I have had a look at the MP4 tags and chapters of a video file with HiLight tags.
- I have mounted the SD card in an SD card reader to be able to see all files on the card (i.e., not just the ones which are visible via [MTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol) when connecting the camera itself). None of the files *seem* to contain the tags.

On a Windows machine I can see the tags in GoPro Studio. My GoPro HERO4 Silver shows the tags on its display in playback mode, too. In the GoPro App I can also see the tags.

### Why do I Need this?

I’m curious! Ok, that’s not the whole story ;) I also work on a Linux machine where GoPro Studio is not available. I would still like to be able to use the created HiLight tags there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’ve found the HiLight tags: they are stored in the MP4 files themselves.

In particular, the tags are stored in a box with type `HMMT` in the User Data Box (`udta`) of the Movie Box (`moov`) of the MPEG-4 container. See [ISO/IEC 14496-12](http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c061988_ISO_IEC_14496-12_2012.zip) for details on these “boxes”.

The `HMMT` box seems to be a non-standard (GoPro-specific) ISO/IEC 14496-12 box. Its data consists of one or more 32-bit integers. The first integer contains the number of available HiLight tags. All subsequent integers resemble an ordered list of HiLight tags. Each HiLight tag is represented as a millisecond value.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do a highlight parser in python. The GoPro-specific box (in `moov`>`udata` as Chriki pointed out) is called `GPMF`. The for the highlights specific labels are `MANLB`. For each highlight there is one `MANLB` [manual label (probably)]. For some reason the time of the highlight in milliseconds is stored three times (*green* in the image)

In a HEX-Editor you can also search for `Highlights`. A few bytes further you can find the `HLMT`-Label (Don't know what this is). After that the manual highlights start.

[click here for an image of the HEX-Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oq8HS.png)

I also wrote a parser in python which extracts the highlights and saves them into a txt-file:
[Link to my GoPro Highlight Parser](https://github.com/icegoogles/GoPro-Highlight-Parser)

A simplified version of searching in the GPMF-Box could look something like this:

```
while offset < end_offset:
    data = f.read(4)               # read box header
    if data == b"": break          # EOF

    if data == b'MANL':

        currPos = f.tell()  # remember current pointer/position
        f.seek(currPos - 20)  # go back to highlight timestamp

        data = f.read(4)  # readout highlight
        timestamp = int.from_bytes(data, "big")  #convert to integer

        if timestamp != 0:
            listOfHighlights.append(timestamp)  # append to highlightlist

        f.seek(currPos)  # go forward again (to the saved position)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code to find these markers, with the PHP Reader library (https://code.google.com/p/php-reader/wiki/ISO14496).

```
require_once 'Zend/Media/Iso14496.php'; 
$isom = new Zend_Media_Iso14496($file);

$hmmt = $isom->moov->udta->HMMT;
if ( isset($hmmt)) {
    $reader = $hmmt->getReader();
    $reader->setOffset($hmmt->getOffset());

    $reader->readHHex(4);//skip some bytes 
    $reader->readHHex(4);//skip some bytes    

    $n = $reader->readInt32BE(); //number of points

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++) {
        $t = $reader->readInt32BE();
        print_r($t); // marker in ms
        echo "\n";
    }
}
```

The getReader() is a function not implemented unfortunately, I hacked it into Zend/Media/Iso14496/Box.php

```
public function getReader() {
    return $this->_reader;
}
```

If you want to do it in java, this library is probably helpfull (it helped me looking into the file in detail) https://github.com/sannies/isoviewer

Answer (score 0):

As of now, at least for GoPro HERO 7 Black, the HiLight tags are stored as chapters in MP4 file. You can see them with VLC, for example (Playback -> Chapter)