# Where are GoPro Highlight Tags stored?

Tags: video, video-editing, mp4, highlighting, gopro

I want to extract the (manually set) highlights from my GoPro-footage (HERO6-Black).
I want to do this to mark the highlights on vacation and can use them to edit in Premiere Pro later.

I found that the Highlights are stored in the mp4-file. So a simple parser that extracts all highlights with a timestamp would be the goal (preferably in python).

The answer to this Question
"https://superuser.com/questions/881661/how-where-does-a-gopro-camera-store-hilight-tags"
suggests they are stored in the mp4-header (`udta` box).
I used a HEX-Editor to find the suggested box but couldn't find anything. Having said this I'm not super familiar doing this!

As the other Question is more than 5 years old they mybe changed something?

I'm also aware of the `GPMF` (https://github.com/gopro/gpmf-parser) but I could not find anything about the highlights, just the sensordata.

I also foud this: https://community.gopro.com/t5/GoPro-Apps-for-Desktop/Where-are-highlight-tags-stored/m-p/525607/highlight/true#/M25010
but I think it refers to the highlights set in the [GoPro-Quick](https://community.gopro.com/t5/en/GoPro-legacy-software/ta-p/595533) software which don't get saved in the mp4-file.

I would appreciate if anyone has an answer or an idea on what I could test.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the highlights and wrote a parser in Python to extract them. As the other question was somewhat similar, I posted my answer in more detail there:

[Link to my answer on the other post](https://superuser.com/a/1588260/1218362)